# CodeIgniter - Correct way to link to another page in a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor

I was wondering if someone could tell me the correct way to link to another page from within a view.

Is there a function for this or is it just the usual about

Comment: how do you want to link it do you want to put a link from one page to the other?

Comment: I'm using relative way. In HTML : `<a href="/controller/method">text</a>` (note / before controller). In PHP code it's without `/`

I'm using rewrite mod and all links are relative to RewriteBase

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**I assume you are meaning "internally" within your application.**

you can create your own `<a>` tag and insert a URL in the href like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>
```

OR you can use the URL helper this way to generate an `<a>` tag

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

So... to use it...

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/function/uri', 'Link', 'class="link-class"') ?>
```

and that will generate

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/controller/function/uri" class="link-class">Link</a>
```

**For the additional commented question**

I would use my first example

so...

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/path/file.jpg" /></a>
```

for images (and other assets) I wouldn't put the file path within the PHP, I would just echo the base_url() and then add the path normally.

Comment: Thanks for that ...What about a link with an image, for example how would i do the following: <a href="link.htm"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/btn-trial.png'; ?>" alt="7 day trial" width="285" height="33" border="0" /></a>

Comment: But here we are passing method name in parameter what if I don't need url as `controller/function` but as `controller/functionChange`? Then in this case I have to change every call of `controller/function` to `controller/functionChange` manually.  is there any other way to achive this as cakephp does like array('controller'=>'controller',method=>'function').

Comment: @jondavidjohn Hi, is `controller/function` strict in CI? Can't I do `controller_to_view/function_to_view/subfolder/actual_view_file`? Because the latter is returning a 404 for me :-(

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>directory_name/filename.php">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use PHP short tag to make it shorter. here's an example

```
<a href="<?= site_url('controller/function'); ?>Contacts</a>
```

or use the built in anchor function of CI.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way is to use anchor tag in CodeIgniter like eg.

```
<?php 
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    echo anchor('name_of_controller_file/function_name_if_any', 'Sign Out', array('class' => '', 'id' => '')); 
?>
```

Refer https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html for details

This will surely work.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use this code

//test" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">

Comment: This does not solve the problem. This is a CSS class.

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>Compose</a>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>Inbox</a>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>Outbox</a>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>logout</a>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function'); ?>logout</a>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: i ithink this is broken tag