# How to set menu links (href) in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to convert my core php project into `CodeIgniter`.
I have set the baseurl for the project in the config file i.e: `http://localhost/myproject/`

When I'm trying to set menu anchor `href` i need to pass `controller_name/action_name`

```
<a href='controller_name/action_name'> Tag_Name
```

I'm not able to set directly the action name for the same controller.

```
<a href='action_name'> Tag_Name
```

I have also loaded the `URL helper` in my Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure you have added this->load->helper('url'); in controller or you can add in config->autoload.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/function')?>"></a>
or
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function')?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>`

or

`<?php echo anchor('controller/function/uri', 'Link', 'class="link-class"') ?>`

Any of the two should be ok. 
Also refer to [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205155/codeigniter-correct-way-to-link-to-another-page-in-a-view)

Or you could use `base_url()` function to get the value set in the config file for `$config['base_url']`.

Comment: actually i'm getting confused. i have created a function name about in devot controller. when i'm calling that function in link why i need to a href= 'devot/about' but in many exmaples i have seen it is simply done as a href='about' only by providing the function name.

Comment: if i pass action_name i get http://localhost/devot/index.php/about - it gives 404 error page

Comment: if i pass controller_name/action_name again i get localhost/devot/index.php/about - it gives 404 error page

Comment: sorry please disregard my previous comment.                                           
if i pass action_name i get localhost/devot/index.php/mycontroller/about    - again it gives 404 error page

Comment: what is $config['index_page'] value in config.php ? Should be null

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/action_name')?>">Tag_name</a>
```

Thanks You