# How to link my site.php page thats a navigation in my home.php with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 php pages I'm working on. 1 is my home.php which is like the index and site is my new page i want to add in my navigation. These 2 files are seperate php files. How can i link site.php when clicked on in my home.php file. I've been trying for hours and can't figure it out. please help.

#Controller#####Site.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

     public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('home');

    }


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('site.php')?>">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i got it!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - Correct way to link to another page in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205155/codeigniter-correct-way-to-link-to-another-page-in-a-view)