# How to give hyperlink to items in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need give some hyperlink to my **items** category in codeigniter.

```
$this->data['itemdata'] = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Printers / Accessories',
                'items' => ['Printers', 'Printer Cartridges', 'Compatible Toners'],

                'brands' => ['hp', 'cannon', 'brother', 'toshiba', 'sharp']
                ),
```

how can I create it?

**Updated**
view file

```
<div class="items">
    <ul class="floated">
        <?php foreach ($item['items'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to do it in view?

Comment: can you see my updated queastion

Comment: <li> <a> <?php echo $value; ?> </a> </li>

Comment: I need href link ??

Comment: got the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it something like below:-

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri');?>"><?php echo $value;?></a></li>
```

Note:- I hope through URL you want to send user to some fruitful link. So change `controller/function/uri` to corresponding values.

Reference:-[CodeIgniter - Correct way to link to another page in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205210/4248328)

Note:- if you want to remove link then do like below:-

```
<li><?php echo $value;?></li>
```

Comment: how to remove hiperlink line in this case?

Comment: @John Just remove that `<a href "#"> </a>` tag