# How to write a link directly inside the Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Actually I want to create a mail which contains some link inside of it to be sent to people.
But I having problems in writing the link as the CodeIgniter can't be treated as a pure PHP script that let us to write it directly to the whichever variable we want.

I've tried to write some of the html code directly to the mail `string variable` that hold the mail message but it doesn't work.
And also I tried to try some of the CI code inside the `string variable` but the code is just treated as it is a plain text.

I already research some of the [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205155/codeigniter-correct-way-to-link-to-another-page-in-a-view) and it told me to create it inside the `view` but this isn't what I expect.

I also have read the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences) and catch one of their statement that says,

> Type of mail. If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete
>   web page. Make sure you don’t have any relative links or relative
>   image paths otherwise they will not work.

A snippet of my codes are like these:

```
public function forgotpassword() {

$receiver = $this->input->post(user');

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('sender@gmail.com', 'Sender');
$this->email->to($receiver);
$this->email->subject('Reset Password');

// Just a testing sample
$link="anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text')";
$msg="Halo, User!\n
Blablabla.\n
Click the link below to proceed.\n
$link\n\n
Best regards.";
$this->email->message($msg);

if($this->email->send())
{
$data['status'] = true;
$data['pesan'] = "Success to send email";
} else {
$data['status'] = false;
$data['pesan'] = "Failed to send email";
}

echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I expect the snippet of codes above will become something like this:

*Halo, User!

Blablabla.

Click the link below to proceed.

[somelink](https://www.google.co.id/)

Best regards.*

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text'); ?>
```

Comment: But I want to insert that example link into my body text sir, so I need to wrap it somehow inside a variable. Your suggested code shows some syntax error T_ECHO

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the strings:

```
$msg="Halo, User!\n
Blablabla.\n
Click the link below to proceed.\n
" . $link . "\n\n
Best regards.";
```

Edit:
Answer to your comment question about html mails.
This is the way i do it with html Emails:
I have an email helper in helpers/MY_email_helper.php

```
<?php
function loadEmailConfig() {
    $instance = get_instance ();
    $instance->load->language ( 'functions/email' );
    $config = array ();
    $config ['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config ['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.xxx.xx';
    $config ['smtp_user'] = 'xxx@xxx.xx';
    $config ['smtp_pass'] = 'xxx';
    $config ['smtp_port'] = 25;
    $config ['mailtype'] = 'html';
    return $config;
}
function my_sendHtmlEmail($receiver, $subject, $html) {
    // --- Send Message ---
    $instance = get_instance ();
    $instance->load->library ( 'email' );
    $instance->email->clear ( TRUE );
    $instance->lang->load ( 'functions/email' );
    $config = loadEmailConfig ();
    $instance->email->initialize ( $config );
    $instance->email->from ( 'your@send-mail.com', 'organisationname' );
    $instance->email->to ( $receiver );
    $instance->email->subject ( $subject );
    $email_data ['message'] = $html;
    $message = $instance->load->view ( 'email/email', $email_data, TRUE );
    $instance->email->message ( $message );
    $bool = $instance->email->send ();
    return $bool;
}
```

the $html argument is the changing content of the mail which i nest into my html email template which is saved in views/email/email.php

then i simply need to load the helper

```
    $this->load->helper('email');
```

and use the function in controller

```
my_sendHtmlEmail('receiver@email.com','subject','<p>html email with <a href""> link</a></p>');
```

Comment: You might want to consider sending html mails so you can make clickable links with html code

Comment: The concatenation is correct, but I found my problem is in the `$link="anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text')";` script. Tried to remove the double quotes but made the script doesn't work.

Yeah I considered to use html formatted message instead of direct message like this, but how? Do you have a good reference about this? I mean, I might be get confused of the html which will be called from the controller

Comment: Wow, will that scripts let me to custom design the email whatever I want? I'll try it soon after i try all of the possibilities for this case. Thanks

Comment: Yes pretty much. Note that not all html tags can be used for emails in order to be displayed correctly in every email client. Have a look here: [link](https://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support) You might want to search for "html email templates".

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just change `$link` to:

```
$link=anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text');
```

anchor creates an absolute link, in your case something like:

> < a href="  http://your_domain/controller/function/parameter.html
>   ">Link Text < /a>

you might want to change `\n` into `<br/>`, which is the html line break

```
$msg="Halo, User!<br/><br />
      Blablabla.<br />
      Click the link below to proceed.<br />
      $link<br /><br />
      Best regards.";
```

this will output:

> Halo, User!
>
> Blablabla.
>
> Click the link below to proceed.
>
> [Link Text](http://your_domain.com/controller/function/parameter.html)
>
> Best regards.

also make sure the URL helper is loaded either in autoload or in the controller before you use anchor() like this: `$this->load->helper('url');`

more info on `anchor()` from the docs [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor)

**edit:** in order to display the link as normal text, you can use the PHP function `htmlentities()`, which converts all applicable characters to HTML entities, like:

```
$link=htmlentities(anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text'));
$msg="Halo, User!\n\n
      Blablabla.\n
      Click the link below to proceed.\n
      $link\n\n
      Best regards.";
```

now the output looks similar to:

> Halo, User!
>
> Blablabla. Click the link below to proceed.
>
> < a
>   href="http://portugal.climbing/controller/function/parameter.html">Link
>   Text< /a>
>
> Best regards.

more on PHP's [htmlentities()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: I added the `$this->load->helper('url');` and it works, but will it only displayed as a plain html tag like this `< a href=" http://your_domain/controller/function/parameter.html ">Link Text < /a>`? Is it possible to only display the [Link Text](https://www.google.co.id/)? And the `</ BR>` html tag is not working, `\n` work fine..

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I've updated my answer, you can use php's htmlentities() to achieve this

Comment: Hm, but `htmlentities()` does the same, moreover it makes sure that the tag used to format the string will be shown as it is, according to [this](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) you see. The documentation told that for example `$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";` will be shown as _// A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;_ if we use `echo htmlentities($str);` :-( CMIIW

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal: using htmlentities(), both (echoing out in browser or sending html email) output `< a href="http://your_site/controller/function/parameter.html">Link Text< /a>`. You might see in your console the HTML entities, but that's not the html output. Also you will need to use `<br/>` in order to get a html line break. Did you ever run the script and check what the email looks like? Maybe there are some other setup problems? On my side I've tested both (echo and email) and it works like you want.

Comment: Yeah I always test it after I changed the scripts but still the tag showed in the email.. to be clear have you know that I intended to write it directly inside the controller, I mean I don't have any html files created? If these solution doesn't work, i'll try the other options..

Comment: Controllers are not for output, views are, and they are html based. In your example, you are embedding $link inside $msg and send it as (html) e-mail. There my example works. You cannot "write directly inside the controller", whatever that means, you can store a value (string) inside a variable, which is later used as view  or email output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one might solve your problem.

```
    $link=anchor('controller/function/parameter', 'Link Text');
    $msg="Halo, User!<br>
    Blablabla.<br>
    Click the link below to proceed.<br>
    $link<br>
    Best regards.";
    echo $msg;
```

try this one out and let me know the result.

Comment: Yeah I tried to remove the double quotes, but it makes the script doesn't work..  And the `</ br>` html tag is not working, `\n` work fine..